# Object detection using Attention Model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision, attention-model

I am using Attention Model for detecting the object in the camera captured image. I have followed show-attend-and-tell (caption generation). But can I find the exact location of the object in the image using show-attend-and-tell (caption generation) ?

Comment: Please provide details on exactly how you have tried to solve the problem but failed.